# Having trouble getting a progress bar to run

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, progress-bar

In my program I have a file input operation that is pretty lengthy. During this operation, my application freezes until the file is loaded (as in, I can't click on anything). Due to this, I am trying to implement a progress bar as a loading screen so that the user does not think something is wrong. I have created a .xaml window with a progress bar and an attached ViewModel and DataModel to facilitate the properties of the progress bar.

For simplicity, the routines that run on file open are located in a large `while` loop. Before this while loop I open the loading window and change the progress bar's `IsIndeterminate` property to `true`.

I only use the `IsIndeterminate` property because I only need the progress bar to look like this:

[image]

However, as I mentioned earlier, during this process my window freezes. This is also causing the progress bar to freeze. How can I display this progress bar and allow it to run while I go through my file input process?

**EDIT**

xaml for Progress Bar:

```
<ProgressBar Name="Progress" Value="{Binding LoadScreenModel.Value}" Minimum="{Binding LoadScreenModel.Min}" Maximum="{Binding LoadScreenModel.Max}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding LoadScreenModel.IsIndeterminate}" />
```

Data Model for Progress Bar window:

```
private int _value, _min = 0, _max = 100; //Progress Bar values
private bool _isIndeterminate;

public LoadingScreenDataModel()
{

}

//Progress Bar values
public int Value{...}
public int Min{...}
public int Max{...}
public bool IsIndeterminate{...}
```

Code in Data Model that runs the File Input routines:

```
var LoadingWindow = new LoadingScreen();
LoadingWindow.Show(); //Open Window w/progress Bar
ViewModel.LoadScreenDataModel.IsIndeterminate = true; 

while()
{... /* Run File input routines **/ ...}

ViewModel.LoadScreenDataModel.IsIndeterminate = false;
LoadingWindow.Close(); //Close Window w/Progress Bar
```

Comment: No code posted means no way to know what you did wrong. That said, "UI not responding" almost always means you are trying to use the UI thread for work (such as "a file input operation that is pretty lengthy") instead of doing that work in a different thread. You should be doing the latter.

Comment: You need to implement a backgroundworker and use reportprogress.

Comment: show your code please otherwise we are as lost in the `Dark` as you are..

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am using the UI thread for the input process. I have suggested multi-threading(to my co-workers), but was told that it wouldn't be a good idea. So basically I need to run my process in it's own thread, and run the progress bar in another?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Sorry, I will add some code. I just thought it was more conceptual.

Comment: @Ericafterdark: yes, you need to run the file input operation in a different thread. The progress bar will stay in the main thread, which is the thread that owns the GUI. See async/await for an easy way to write the code that deals with showing the progress bar, starting the file input operation and waiting for it, and then closing the progress bar when it's done. This allows you to write something that is _semantically_ a wait, but which does not actually block the GUI thread.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Great, I am in the process of investigating multi-threading for this process. Thank you for clearing that up for me.